# How much bandwidth has been used in my app

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I'm developing android app. I call

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) fileURLInfo.openConnection();
```

to get file download information(file name, file size, format, ...) if everything is OK call

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(fileURLFile.openStream());
```

to download file.

My question is how much data amount app has been used for two step? (Double of file download size or single of file download size). Thanks